# Setting italic text for a certain portion of the text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsregularexpression

I am using TTTAttributedLabel(https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) and using it to set the italic text for those in the parentheses. The problem is the text in the parentheses is not set to italic. Not sure where my error is..

The code looks like this:

```
static inline NSRegularExpression * ParenthesisRegularExpression() {
    static NSRegularExpression *_parenthesisRegularExpression = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _parenthesisRegularExpression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\\([^\\(\\)]+\\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });

    return _parenthesisRegularExpression;
}

-(TTTAttributedLabel*)setItalicTextForLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel fontSize:(float)Size stringToBeSet:(NSString*)string
{
    [attributedLabel setText:string afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString)
    {
        NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length]);
        NSRegularExpression *regexp = ParenthesisRegularExpression();
        [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:[mutableAttributedString string] options:0 range:stringRange usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
            UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:Size];
            CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
            if (italicFont) {
                [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName range:result.range];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)italicFont range:result.range];
                CFRelease(italicFont);

                [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName range:result.range];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor] range:result.range];
            }
        }];

        return mutableAttributedString;
    }];
    return attributedLabel;
}
```

I am calling it this way:`mylabel = [self setItalicTextForLabel:descriptionLabel fontSize:23 stringToBeSet:string];`

Need some guidance on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I see you are also changing the color. Does the color change? (On a side note, move `italicSystemFont` and `italicFont` declaration and releases outside of the block. Blocks "inherit" variables "above" their scope.)

Comment: yes.. the color does change under my code....

Comment: What's in `italicSystemFont.fontName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used `TTTAttributedLabel`, and my experience with `NSAttributedString` comes from playing with `NSTextView` on OS X.

That said, why not refactor the code a bit to pass an `NSAttributedString` directly into `setText:afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:`? That scenario seems to have been [made possible two years ago](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/25).

In fact, why not use `setText:`?

> Sets the text displayed by the label.
>
> **@param text** An `NSString` or `NSAttributedString` object to be displayed by the label. If the specified text is an `NSString`, the label will display the text like a `UILabel`, inheriting the text styles of the label. If the specified text is an `NSAttributedString`, the label text styles will be overridden by the styles specified in the attributed string.
>
> **@discussion** This method overrides `UILabel -setText:` to accept both `NSString` and `NSAttributedString` objects. This string is `nil` by default.

I've taken the liberty of renaming your method and cleaning up the code. Without testing, of course, considering that I don't have `TTTAttributedLabel` available, and am too lazy to set up a demo project just to answer this question :-)

```
-(void)applyItalicTextInParenthesisOfString:(NSString*)string
                                    toLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel
                                     fontSize:(float)size
{
    NSMutableAttributedString * mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length]);
    NSRegularExpression *regexp = ParenthesisRegularExpression();

    UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:size];
    CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);

    [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:[mutableAttributedString string] options:0 range:stringRange usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

        if (italicFont)
        {
            // No need to remove an attribute; the string was already an
            // NSString, without any attributes.
            // [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName range:result.range];
            // [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName range:result.range];

            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)italicFont range:result.range];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor] range:result.range];
        }
    }];

    CFRelease(italicFont);

    [attributedLabel setText:string]
}
```

I'm also somewhat old-fashioned, so for readability, I'd avoid ARC and blocks.

Comment: Alternatively, consider setting some more exotic font name, and doing it manually, to see if font is being applied in the first place, or if the fact that the font is italic is troublesome.

Comment: firstly thanks for replying.. the regular expression match is correct. but the font setting is wrong... i will try to set it manually first...

Comment: @lakesh You piqued my interest -- what part of the above code is iOS 6 specific? :-)

Comment: It was a iOS 6 specific code that I had in my code before this had caused this problem...

Comment: Can you help me out with the changes required to be made for iOS7. I am getting a lot of errors on using the above code.